# Intrexx - Trigger workflow by javascript

Tags: javascript, workflow, intrexx

I am using Intrexx portal manager.

How can I trigger a workflow (by guid) in javascript.
I need to fill data manually.

Thanks and best regards
Gustav Wurstgustav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
triggerUserWorkflowEvent("GUID", {
   "param1": "value1",
   "param2": "value2"
});
```

Documentation: https://onlinehelp.unitedplanet.com/intrexx/9200/en/?p=helpfiles/help.2.tipps-tricks-prozesse-starten.html